# Getting 502 - Bad Gateway errors on a Kentico site running in an Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kentico

I have a Kentico website running in an Azure App Service, and i am getting 502 - Bad Gateway errors for some of the static resources (images) that the website tries to load.

If i try to load the homepage for example, using HTTPS i get these errors, but using HTTP i don't get them.

Comment: what was the method used Azure marketplace / visual studio / ftp ?

Comment: @ZahidFaroq i used Azure Devops to deploy the website, and used FTP to deploy the website media. I recreated everything and the error is gone again. It is quite confusing this issue. I involved microsoft support team and they are analysing the crash dumps.

Comment: @HugoBarona Did you get anywhere with this? We are seeing a similar issue.

Comment: @DanFriedman Azure team was involved to troubleshoot the problem, but they did not find anything. they analyzed dumps, configurations, etc. In the meanwhile I recreated the App Service again, did everything as before, and the problem was gone. are you using app service + kentico site? or any other app?

Answer (score 0):

502 HTTP error is an invalid response from the server. Are those static resources loaded through HTTPS as well? You can check that in the Network tab of the browser console.

If not, could you make sure your website is configured correctly for HTTPS per Kentico documentation - [Configuring SSL](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/securing-websites/deploying-websites-to-a-secure-environment/configuring-ssl)?

Comment: Filipo, this kentico website is running in our Production On-premises environment, and it is using HTTPS, so it is not the case of bad configuration in terms of SSL. On Friday, i basically decided to recreate the App Service and the problems went away. I believe the problem was that i initially was running some commands in Kudu to manage deployments of the website, and somehow the instance of the App Service got invalid. Recreating the App Service fixed the problem.

Comment: actually, the problem is back. It is quite confusing what's happening with this. Anyway, in relation with your comment, i am using App Service and the built-in certificate. I disabled the option to force HTTPS, so accessing the home page using HTTP is returning still the 502 - Bad Gateway errors for static resources. It is also important to understand that it is not returning 502 for all static resources, so some of the images, css, js files it is able to load properly.